# The <mat-form-field> Tag restricts the width of the form and doesn't match the width of the container

Tags: angular, html, angular-material

I am editing a form using Angular, but it doesn't work well. When I was debugging it using the Chrome dev tool, I found out that the mat-form-field restricts the width of the input area, and I didn't put any CSS code to specify the width.

The width of form and p tag: 460, the width of mat-form-field: 180. I didn't put any style to the code except for the container part.

[image: An illustration of the problem]

```
<div class="container"
fxLayout="row"
fxLayout.sm="column"
fxLayout.xs="column"
fxLayoutAlign.gt-md="space-around center"
fxLayoutGap="20px" 
fxLayoutGap.xs="0">

<div fxFlex *ngIf="dish">
...
</div>

<div fxFlex *ngIf="dish" class="full-width">
    <h3>
      <b>Comments</b>
    </h3>
    <mat-list *ngIf="dish.comments">
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let comment of dish.comments">
          <p matline>
          <span>{{comment.comment}}<br></span>
          <span>{{comment.rating}} Stars<br></span>
          <span>-- {{comment.author}} {{comment.date | date}}</span>
          </p>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>

    <form novalidate #fform="ngForm" [formGroup]="commentForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <p>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="name" placeholder="name" type="text" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.name">{{formErrors.name}}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </p>
    <p>
      <mat-slider thumbLabel tickInterval="1" min="0" max="5" value="5"></mat-slider>
    </p>
    <p>
      <mat-form-field>
        <textarea matInput formControlName="comment" placeholder="comment" rows=8 required></textarea>
        <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.comment">{{formErrors.comment}}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </p>
      <button type="submit" mat-button class="background-primary text-floral-white" [disabled]="!commentForm.valid">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div [hidden]="dish">
  <mat-spinner></mat-spinner><h4>Loading . . . Please Wait</h4>
</div>
```

I want to match the mat-form-field width to the form width, from 180 to 460. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Apply a `width: 100%` to the mat-form-field element; that will cause it to match the width of its parent. You might need to play around a little with the styling of the containing elements to get the exact look you want.